Calculate position of point along edge of regular polygon?
Say I have a pentagon (and we number the sides, like moving around a clock):

Starting from the center of the polygon, how do you compute the position of a point in these spots (along the line of the edge of the polygon):

At the vertex between sides 2 and 3 (this is the max distance from the center).
At the midpoint of 4 (this is the min distance from the center).
At a point 2/3 across side 3, moving clockwise (randomly chosen distance from the center).

Knowing how to compute the x/y coordinates relative to the center will mean I can plot points along the straight line-segments of an arbitrary polygon (ranging from say 3 to 20 sides). I am having a really time conceptualizing how to do this, let alone getting it to work in code. Doesn't matter what language it is in, but preferably JavaScript/TypeScript, or else Python or C (or self-explanatory pseudocode).
Here is a combination of what I conjured up. The polygon layout works properly, but the point positioning isn't working. How do you layout these 3 points?


const ANGLE = -Math.PI / 2 // Start the first vertex at the top center

function computePolygonPoints({
  width,
  height,
  sides,
  strokeWidth = 0,
  rotation = 0,
}) {
  const centerX = width / 2 + strokeWidth / 2
  const centerY = height / 2 + strokeWidth / 2
  const radiusX = width / 2 - strokeWidth / 2
  const radiusY = height / 2 - strokeWidth / 2
  const offsetX = strokeWidth / 2
  const offsetY = strokeWidth / 2

  const rotationRad = (rotation * Math.PI) / 180

  const points = Array.from({ length: sides }, (_, i) => {
    const angle = (i * 2 * Math.PI) / sides + ANGLE
    const x = centerX + radiusX * Math.cos(angle)
    const y = centerY + radiusY * Math.sin(angle)

    // Apply rotation around the center
    const rotatedX =
      centerX +
      (x - centerX) * Math.cos(rotationRad) -
      (y - centerY) * Math.sin(rotationRad)
    const rotatedY =
      centerY +
      (x - centerX) * Math.sin(rotationRad) +
      (y - centerY) * Math.cos(rotationRad)

    return { x: rotatedX, y: rotatedY }
  })

  const minX = Math.min(...points.map(p => p.x))
  const minY = Math.min(...points.map(p => p.y))

  const adjustedPoints = points.map(p => ({
    x: offsetX + p.x - minX,
    y: offsetY + p.y - minY,
  }))

  return adjustedPoints
}

function vertexCoordinates(n, R, vertexIndex) {
  const angle = 2 * Math.PI * vertexIndex / n - Math.PI / 2; // Adjusting to start from the top
  return {
    x: R * Math.cos(angle),
    y: R * Math.sin(angle),
  }
}

function midpointCoordinates(x1, y1, x2) {
  return {
    x: (x1 + x2.x) / 2,
    y: (y1 + x2.y) / 2,
  }
}

function fractionalPoint(x1, y1, x2, fraction) {
  return {
    x: x1 + fraction * (x2.x - x1),
    y: y1 + fraction * (x2.y - y1),
  }
}

const pentagonPoints = computePolygonPoints({ width: 300, height: 300, sides: 5 })

const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svg.setAttribute("width", 300)
svg.setAttribute("height", 300);

const pentagon = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
pentagon.setAttribute('fill', 'cyan')
pentagon.setAttribute('points', pentagonPoints
  .map((p) => `${p.x},${p.y}`)
  .join(" "))

svg.appendChild(pentagon)
document.body.appendChild(svg);

const n = 5 // Number of sides for a pentagon
const width = 300; // Width of the pentagon
const R = width / (2 * Math.cos(Math.PI / n)); // Radius of the circumscribed circle

const centerX = 150; // Center of the canvas
const centerY = 150;

// Vertex between sides 2 and 3
const vertex23 = vertexCoordinates(n, R, 2)
const vertex23Adjusted = {
    x: centerX + vertex23.x, // subtract radius too?
    y: centerY + vertex23.y
};
console.log('Vertex between sides 2 and 3:', vertex23Adjusted)

const circle23 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
circle23.setAttribute('fill', 'magenta')
circle23.setAttribute('r', 16)
circle23.setAttribute('cx', vertex23Adjusted.x)
circle23.setAttribute('cy', vertex23Adjusted.y)
svg.appendChild(circle23)

// Midpoint of side 4
const vertex4_1 = vertexCoordinates(n, R, 3)
const vertex4_2 = vertexCoordinates(n, R, 4)
const mid4 = midpointCoordinates(vertex4_1.x, vertex4_1.y, vertex4_2)
console.log('Midpoint of side 4:', mid4)

const mid4Circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
mid4Circle.setAttribute('fill', 'magenta')
mid4Circle.setAttribute('r', 16)
mid4Circle.setAttribute('cx', mid4.x)
mid4Circle.setAttribute('cy', mid4.y)
svg.appendChild(mid4Circle)

// Point 2/3 across side 3, moving clockwise
const vertex3_1 = vertexCoordinates(n, R, 2)
const vertex3_2 = vertexCoordinates(n, R, 3)
const frac3 = fractionalPoint(
  vertex3_1.x,
  vertex3_1.y,
  vertex3_2,
  2 / 3,
)
console.log('Point 2/3 across side 3:', frac3)

const frac3Circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
frac3Circle.setAttribute('fill', 'magenta')
frac3Circle.setAttribute('r', 16)
frac3Circle.setAttribute('cx', frac3.x)
frac3Circle.setAttribute('cy', frac3.y)
svg.appendChild(frac3Circle)



I'd like to be able to solve this for any polygon from 3 to 20 sides, not just for the pentagon.

Pardon me but I still don't understand which points you're trying to calculate. You already have the vertices coordinates when generating the pentagon. So you could linearly interpolate points between all edges based on start and end point(vertex) at a given t value. See codepen: https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/ZENLmGv?editors=0010

So  1. At the vertex between sides 2 and 3 (this is the max distance from the center). should actually be pentagonPoints[2] (3rd point from the retrieved polygon point array). Could it be you're trying  to find points on the polygon at certain angles?

Here is the answer, I finally figured it out.
export function calculatePolygonDotPosition({
  polygonRadius,
  polygonSideCount,
  polygonEdgeNumber,
  polygonEdgePositionRatio, // from 0 to 1
  gap = 0,
  dotRadius,
  rotation = 0,
  offset = 0,
}: {
  polygonRadius: number
  polygonSideCount: number
  polygonEdgeNumber: number
  polygonEdgePositionRatio: number
  gap?: number
  dotRadius: number
  rotation?: number
  offset?: number
}) {
  const n = polygonSideCount
  const R = polygonRadius
  const e = polygonEdgeNumber
  const t = polygonEdgePositionRatio
  const o = gap

  const rotationAngle = (rotation * Math.PI) / 180

  const V1 = rotatePoint(getPolygonVertex(e - 1, n, R), rotationAngle)
  const V2 = rotatePoint(getPolygonVertex(e % n, n, R), rotationAngle) // Wrap around using modulo

  // Interpolate position along the edge
  const P = {
    x: (1 - t) * V1.x + t * V2.x,
    y: (1 - t) * V1.y + t * V2.y,
  }

  // Calculate the edge vector and the normal vector
  const dx = V2.x - V1.x
  const dy = V2.y - V1.y
  const edgeLength = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

  // Unit normal vector (rotate by 90 degrees counter-clockwise)
  const normal = {
    x: -dy / edgeLength,
    y: dx / edgeLength,
  }

  // Offset the point by the gap distance
  const P_offset = {
    x: P.x + (-o - dotRadius + offset) * normal.x,
    y: P.y + (-o - dotRadius + offset) * normal.y,
  }

  return {
    x: P_offset.x + R,
    y: -P_offset.y + R,
  }
}

// Calculate vertex positions
export function getPolygonVertex(i: number, n: number, R: number) {
  const angle = (2 * Math.PI * i) / n + Math.PI / 2
  return { x: R * Math.cos(angle), y: R * Math.sin(angle) }
}

function rotatePoint(
  { x, y }: { x: number; y: number },
  angle: number,
) {
  const cos = Math.cos(angle)
  const sin = Math.sin(angle)
  return {
    x: x * cos - y * sin,
    y: x * sin + y * cos,
  }
}

Usage:
calculatePolygonDotPosition({
  polygonRadius: 300,
  polygonSideCount: 5,
  polygonEdgeNumber: 2,
  polygonEdgePositionRatio: 0.5,
  gap: 4,
  dotRadius: 3,
  offset: 4, // strokeWidth
})

Here are 4 points laid out just outside the outer edge.


The problem with your trigonometrical computation is that the circumscribed circle is too big. You can see it if you add
<circle cx="«centerX»" cy="«centerY»" r="«R»"/>

to your diagram:

But you need not do the computation yourself, you can let SVG do it for you with the path.getPointAtLength(length) function. In your cases,

the vertex between sides 2 and 3 is at length=2
the midpoint of 4 is at length=3.5
a point 2/3 across side 3, moving clockwise, is at length=2.67.



var path = document.querySelector("polygon");
var circle = document.querySelector("circle");
var control = document.querySelector("input[type=range]");

function init(n) {
  control.setAttribute("max", n);
  var d = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var alpha = 2 * i * Math.PI / n;
    d.push(`${Math.sin(alpha)},${-Math.cos(alpha)}`);
  }
  path.setAttribute("points", d.join(" "));
  control.value = 0;
  move();
}

function move() {
  var p = path.getPointAtLength(path.getTotalLength() * control.value / control.getAttribute("max"));
  circle.setAttribute("cx", p.x);
  circle.setAttribute("cy", p.y);
  control.nextElementSibling.textContent = control.value;
}

init(5);
polygon {
  fill: yellow;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 0.01;
}

circle {
  fill: red;
}
<input type="number" value="5" onchange="init(this.value)" />
<svg viewBox="-1 -1 2 2">
    <polygon/>
    <circle r="0.1"/>
</svg>
<input type="range" step="0.01" onchange="move()" /><span></span>




I was hoping to get more abstract with the calculations, as I don't want to lay them on the polygon edge exactly, but offset from the edge by a certain gap. I guess I could just draw another polygon hidden... But it would be nice to know how to do this without relying on SVG helpers. My code also always puts a flat edge at the bottom.
